# Run mapserver under installed xampp

Tags: mapserver, windows-7, apache

I'm running xampp in windows 7, apache is listening port 80.

I downloaded MS4W and installed the bundle under c:\ms4w and configured apache to listen on port 8080.

I'm running htt://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe and I'm getting the following output

> No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty.

which according the instructions shows that mapserver is running. I also executed the following example htt://127.0.0.1:8080/quickmap.php which also run with no problems.

Then I copied all the cgi-bin from ms4w/apache to xampp/apache.
I also searched the ms4w httpd.conf, in the ms4w/appache/conf, for mapserver and transferred the following to xampp apache configuration.

```
## Alias for MapServer tmp directory
Alias /ms_tmp/ "C:/xampp/tmp/ms_tmp/"  

# set environment vars necessary for MapServer
SetEnv PROJ_LIB "C:/xampp/ms4w/proj/nad/"
SetEnv PATH "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin/" 

# uncomment the following lines to log MapServer errors to a file
#SetEnv MS_ERRORFILE "C:/xampp/tmp/ms_error.txt"
#SetEnv MS_DEBUGLEVEL 3
```

Restarting apache under xampp and executing http://localhost:80/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe and as a result I'm getting

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with permissions, try `chmod -R 777 xamp/`

Comment: @Grey I'm using windows 7 and I have logged in with admin account.

Comment: what happens if you just try `localhost/cgi-bin/mapserver.exe`? ie. without the port?

Comment: you also should add as tags `windows` and `xampp` in order to bring the attention of windows users, I work on unix-like environments.

Comment: Without port 80 I'm getting the same error.

Comment: have you include xampp / apache cgi-bin dir in your environment path?

Comment: @Zenn This was the source of my trouble. I had included the environment path but I copied cgi-bin in xampp dir and in xampp/apache. Unfortunately in xampp/apache there was already a cgi-bin directory which fooled me when I was rechecking.